# Struts logic tag with session variables

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

Following code prints 0 values in the table column. But it is not supposed to print since in the logic equal it checks whether the value is 1.

```
<logic:equal name="humpRoadFlag" value="1" scope="session">
           <td title='<bean:message key="prompt.block_to" />'><%= session.getAttribute("humpRoadFlag") %></td>

</logic:equal>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the type of `humpRoadFlag`?

Comment: It's a string 0 or 1

Comment: Should work as-is assuming you're correct about its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be included in the jsp page.

```
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglib/struts-logic.tld"     prefix="logic" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip using the logic tag using java code in the JSP , if still printing '0', the value assigned to humpRoadFlag in session , is not what is intended to be.

```
 <%=String humpRoadFlagValue =(String)session.getAttribute("humpRoadFlag");
    if(humpRoadFlagValue.compareTo("0")!=0){%>
    <td title='<bean:message key="prompt.block_to" />'><%=humpRoadFlagValue %></td>
<%=}%>
```